# hbase.master vs zookeeper details in HBase connection using Java API

Tags: hadoop, hbase

What is the benefits of using both

- `hbase.master`
- `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` & `hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort`

in creating connection with HBase using Java API?

Sample code:

```
Configuration hBaseConfig =  HBaseConfiguration.create();
hBaseConfig.set("hbase.master",  hbaseHost +":"+ port);
hBaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",zookeeperHost);
hBaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
```

Which out of these details is sufficient or I need both?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your query by splitting it up ..

Q1 . What is the benefits of using both

```
hbase.master
hbase.zookeeper.quorum & hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort
```

in creating connection with HBase using Java API?

**Solution** : Regarding benefit you would be able to access the hbase using the java api,for which the hbase master and zookeeper service must be up in your server which is **mandatory** .

Q2 : Sample code:

```
Configuration hBaseConfig =  HBaseConfiguration.create();
hBaseConfig.set("hbase.master",  hbaseHost +":"+ port);
hBaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum",zookeeperHost);
hBaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
```

Which out of these details is sufficient or I need both?

Solution : you would require both , however you could also add "**hbase-site,xml**" in your classpath , which would be available under hbase/conf directory in the machine where hbase is installed. Along with that you need to add "**core-site.xml**" under hadoop/conf directory .

For more information : " https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_examples "
    check out the link.